# How to bind multiple events on a images in adaptive cards

Tags: json, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to achieve following scenarios through adaptive cards. I have tried many ways but still not able to reach any far by my expectation.

**Scenario one**

I am trying to build a feedback rating card which has 3 images. As soon as a user clicks on any of the image, I would like both Action.ToggleVisibility and Action.Submit event to trigger at the same time. Is it possible to bind two events on a image in adaptive cards?

**Scenario two**

Since the first option did not work for me, I tried to add the radio buttons along with the existing images and a Submit button separately. But this time, It was found that the radio button does not have an option to associate an image with it. Also, the alignment of the choice set cannot be changed from vertical to horizontal. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Are you building a Bot Framework bot? What channel is it for?

Comment: Yes, webchat and directline

Comment: So you're talking about [Adaptive Card feedback controls](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3054) and [rating controls](https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/c/8-rating-control), right? You want to send a message to the bot and also alter the look of the card with one click. Adaptive Cards don't have that feature yet, but in Teams you can respond to the submit action by updating the activity. Are you trying to manipulate Web Chat in such a way that it can trigger two actions with one click, or perhaps so that it can update messages?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to implement in web chat. I see that it is in the product backlog. Any idea when is it going to be generally available?

Comment: I don't know any more than you do about the timeline involved. I believe I can answer your question with a workaround at the very least, but first can you post your card's JSON so I can work off of that?

Comment: Do you still need help?